# Linq-to-sql query error with StartsWith

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQPad to run the following query:

```
var pds = (from p in Projects
            group p by p.FiscalYearVariables.FiscalYear into grouped
            where grouped.Count() > 0
            select new { 
                fiscalYear = grouped.Key,
                projectDetails = grouped.SelectMany(a=>a.ProjectDetails),
                Programs = (from pwbs in Programs.SelectMany(a =>a.ProgramWbsNumbers)
                            let ds = pwbs.WbsNumbers.DisplayString
                            where pwbs.Programs.IsActive
                            && (from w in WbsNumbers
                                where w.DisplayString.StartsWith(ds)
                                select w).Any()
                            select pwbs.Programs)
            });

            pds.Dump();
```

And I get the error:

> NotSupportedException: Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.StartsWith method.

I'm not sure how to go about correcting this error. I need to get each `Program` where the `WbsNumber` starts with the `WbsNumber` contained within `ProgramWbsNumbers` if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
where SqlMethods.Like(w.DisplayString, ds + "%")
```